# contenido se superpone sobre el menu wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

junto con saludar, estoy por acá nuevamente con un pequeño problemilla..
me toca crear una pagina en wordpress, bajo un tema llamado windsor, el problema que por lo que veo viene fallado el menu...

la pagina es https://mindshot.cl/rbpropiedades/ si se dan cuenta al bajar, el menu queda por debajo de los elementos y no se ve bien.

me gustaria que el menu quedara siempre por encima de los elementos, pero no he podido lograrlo, he probado con z-index pero no me funciona, tampoco hay alguna opcion en el administrador o en las opciones del tema para lograr esto, de que manera se podria realizar?

Comment: En **Apariencia -> Personalizar -> CSS Adicional** agrega la siguiente regla: `.top_panel.without_bg_image { z-index: 500 !important; }` Aclaro que no es muy recomendable este tipo de soluciones, pero ya hay una propiedad similar que es la que hace que el panel aparezca debajo.

Comment: me sirvió lo que me dijiste. Pero luego encontré el origen real del error. Era un css que tenia adicional, para unos cuadros que estaba realizando y ocupe la palabra "promo", luego me di cuenta que promo esta siendo utilizado por la plantilla. Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, mantendré el código guardado en caso de jaja.